# Hebrew and digits mixture

Tags: text, hebrew

I want to write some text which includes Hebrew characters and numbers (by copy-pasting them, only for mathematical notation), specifically aleph-one (without access to MathJax or LaTeX).

The problem is that when I paste א and try to write the digit 1 next to it (without space in between), it appears on the left, no matter where the cursor is. I tried to work around it in a few ways and it doesn't seem to work any way I tried -- the aleph always appears to the right of the 1. Is this a bug? If not, how am I supposed to do it?

The version is 16.04. The issue occurs in any textarea.

Comment: Select the `1א` string and right-click. I have an option "Writing direction..." there, don't you? Choose "Right to left". (this will also right-justify the selected text, which may not be what you want.)

Comment: @Joe: I can't see this option. Not in Firefox (where I want to do it) and not in gedit. I don't want the text to be right-justified, but I suspect it doesn't matter (as I was going to write it in a CMS). By the way, I just put in \aleph_1.

Comment: I don't have such an option in gedit either, and I don't have Firefox but I have it in Chrome.